# ms access change report RecordSource with form

Tags: forms, ms-access, report

I have a form, and I want it to be able to save a copy of a table, and the resulting report. I also want the recordsource of the report to change to the new table's name.
I've got the copies of report and table down, I just can't figure out the RecordSource part.

```
Dim tabName As String
tabName = Text255.Value

DoCmd.CopyObject , tabName, acTable, "MPO"
DoCmd.CopyObject , tabName, acReport, "MPO"
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't change the report. Use a query as source for the report.

Before opening the report, adjust the SQL of the query:

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim qd As DAO.QueryDef

Set db = CurrentDb
Set qd = db.QueryDefs("NameOfYourQuery")
qd.SQL = "Select * From " & YourNewTableName & ""
qd.Close

Set qd = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
```

Comment: Sorry it took so long to respond back, I haven't been working on this since the day I posted. Can you explain exactly what that code does? I tried to read the Microsoft explanation, but my ADD got the best of me with their long sentences.

Comment: It changes the SQL of the query that is the source for your report to the new table's name. As you requested.

Comment: I'm still not quite following. I posted my code, so maybe you can explain it more specifically.

Comment: Perhaps you should rephrase your question. I have never had a need to call CopyObject, neither am I familiar with the meaning of "the resulting report of a table".